# The Final Image?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, lenses, telescopes

[image]

I can't understand that if these lines are parallel to each other how and where the final image would form?

Comment: Far away. Like the distant object (a galaxy maybe) is far away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This telescope does not form a real image, but when you put your
eye up to it, your lens focuses parallel rays to a point on your
retina.

Light from a distant object (like the sun) is nearly-parallel,
which is why you cannot tell the distance from the sun as you
would nearby items (parallax from two eyes).  A usual test
for an optical system is to use parallel light rays (from
a collimator, or just from the sun on a sunny day) and
observe an image on a screen, but this telescope does not make
such an image by itself.